# Python Problem: applied problem for building function for retrieving the elements from the list

Tags: python, function

Problem:
There is a marathon, and you have a list of the participants. (ex: ["jack", "mike", "john"])
The number of participants is random integer between 1 to 100000.
You also have list of participants who completed the marathon. The number of the participants who completed is 1 less than the total participants.
There could be participants who have same name.
You have to build a function that would print the participant who didn't complete the marathon.

**My attempt:**

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    for i in completion:
        if i in participant:
            participant.remove(i)
    answer = print ('"' + str(*participant) + '"')
    return(answer)
```

For example, if participant = ["john", "mike"], completion = ["john"],
The expected answer is "mike"
I think there is nothing wrong with the code I attempted.
If there is, could you guys point out the part I missed?
Most importantly, is there a more elegant way of building this function?

Comment: How could someone complete the marathon without participating?

Comment: Wrong forum ... but: use collections.Counter on both lists and subtract the values of the keys of the 2nd from the 1st one. That would be MUCH faster.

Comment: `from collections import Counter` - `a,b = Counter(list("rrbbggrr")),Counter(list("rrbbggr"))` - `print((a-b).most_common()[0][0])`

Comment: @PatrickArtner `print(*(a-b))`.

Comment: Why did you accept a wrong answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Two possible improvements: 1st, if always only one participant doen't completed.

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    for p in participant:
        if p not in completion:
            print( p )
            return p
```

2nd if n participant didn't completed:

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer = []
    for p in participant:
        if p not in completion:
            print( p )
            answer.add(append)
    
    #print( answer ) # if needed
    return answer
```

If you use sets instead, you can simply sustract them

```
def short(participant, completion):
    return set(participant) - set(completion)
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp

A small hint:
Also your
`answer = print ('"' + str(*participant) + '"')` only works on Python 3, Python2 raises a SyntaxError, because print doesn't return anything (what is None in Python 3).

Comment: All your solutions fail for example `solution(['jack', 'jack'], ['jack'])`.

Comment: Yeah, the shown examples sadly don't cover it, but I doubt they'd explicitly say "There could be participants who have same name" if that weren't important.

Answer (score -2):

```
    for i in completion:
        if i in participant:
            participant.pop(i)
    answer = print ('"' + str(*participant) + '"')
    return(answer)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.

Comment: I saw the question on my phone at the time and it was too difficult to write up a lot there and then.
My other answers have been in more detail. Appreciate the feedback however.